# Using the convolution formula for density

Tags: probability-theory

$X,Y$ are independent and $Z=X+Y$.

$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{5}x & 0\leq x\leq 5 \\ 0 & else \end{cases}$

$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}y & 0\leq y\leq 2 \\ 0 & else \end{cases}$

I want to calculate the density $f_Z(z)$ of $Z$.

Using the convolution formula: $f_Z(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(u-x) dx=\int_0^5 (\frac{1}{5}x)(\frac{1}{2}(u-x)1_{\{0\leq u-x \leq 2\}}) dx=\frac{1}{10}\int_0^5 (xu-x^{2})1_{\{u-2\leq x \leq u \}}dx=\frac{1}{10}\int_{max(0,u-2)}^{min(5,u)} xu-x^{2} dx$

How do I proceed with the integral limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to write
\begin{aligned}
f_Z(u) &= \frac{1}{10}\int_{\max (0,u-2)}^{\min (5,u)} xu - x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \frac{u}{10}\int_{\max (0,u-2)}^{\min (5,u)} x \,\mathrm{d}x - \frac{1}{10} \int_{\max (0,u-2)}^{\min (5,u)} x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{u \left(\min (5,u)^2 - \max (0,u-2)^2\right)}{20}  - \frac{\min (5,u)^3 - \max (0,u-2)^3}{30} \\
&= \left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\frac{u^3}{60}  &\text{if}\quad u < 2 \\
\displaystyle\frac{u^3 - u (u-2)^2}{20} - \frac{u^3 - (u-2)^3}{30} &\text{if}\quad 2 < u < 5 \\
\displaystyle\frac{25 u - u (u-2)^2}{20} - \frac{125 - (u-2)^3}{30} &\text{if}\quad 5 < u
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Im having trouble understanding how I continue after this, what are the values of $u$?

Comment: Not really, its not the calculations that I'm having trouble with. Rather how I determine $\min(5,u)$ and $\max(0,u-2)$..

Comment: Yeah, but what are the values of $u$? How do I determine if $5 <u$ ?

Comment: You can be a bit more explicit by splitting into 3 cases, which might be more like what the OP has in mind.

Comment: So Im not sure if I've understood this right..should I just leave the expression $\frac{u \left(\min (5,u)^2 - \max (0,u-2)^2\right)}{20}  - \frac{\min (5,u)^3 - \max (0,u-2)^3}{30}$ as $f_Z(z)$? Or should I determine the value of $\min(5,u)$ and $\max(0,u-2)$ ?

Comment: Or I think I understood it now, we will have different explicit expressions for $f_Z(u)$ depending on $\min(5,u)$ and $\max(0,u-2)$?

Comment: By the way, is this the "way" to approach the convolution-integral by involving min/max? Or does there happen to exist a more easier approach of this problem?

Comment: When the PDFs have indicator functions, it is usual to deal with $\min$ and $\max$.